Does every triangle satisfy $- \frac{1}{2r} < \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} - \frac{1}{c} < \frac{1}{2r}$ where $r$ is the inradius?
Experimental evidences suggests that the following inequalities holds.

Reciprocal triangle inequality: In any non-degenerate triangle, the sum of the reciprocals of any two sides is less than the sum of the reciprocal of the third side and half the reciprocal of the inradius.

Let $(a,b,c)$ be the length of the sides of a non-degenerate triangle inscribed on a circle of radius $R$, inradius $r$ and area $A$; then,
$$
- \frac{1}{2r} < \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} - \frac{1}{c} < \frac{1}{2r}
$$
and
$$
- \frac{R}{A} < \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} - \frac{1}{c} < \frac{R}{A}
$$
Note that for reciprocals, the triangle must be non-degenerate to avoid division by zero. The inequalities are not tight instead, the upper and and the lower bounds are approached only when the triangle approaches degeneracy with one side approaching zero length and the other two sides approaching $2R$ where $R$ is the circumradius.
Generalization: For all $x \ge 1$,
$$
-\frac{1}{2^x r^x} < \frac{1}{a^x} + \frac{1}{b^x} - \frac{1}{c^x} <  \frac{1}{2^x r^x}
$$
and
$$
-\left(\frac{R}{A}\right)^x < \frac{1}{a^x} + \frac{1}{b^x} - \frac{1}{c^x} <  \left(\frac{R}{A}\right)^x.
$$
Can these proved?

You aren't a newcomer to the site : why don't you say more about the case $x=1$ ? In particular in such inequalities, it is important to say whether they are tight or not... Have you attempted : equilateral, right angle, isosceles cases ?

You've changed the inequalities from the forms originally posted. Were the old ones incorrect? Are the new ones "better" is some way? ... Also, to be clear: Does $A$ indicate area?

@Blue Yes $A$ is a area of the triangle. I fixed a typpo and as auggested in the comment by Jean, added some additional information such and info about tightness, approaching equality and gave the lower bound for the case $x=1$

Wouldn't $a,b \rightarrow 2R$, $c \rightarrow 0$ lead to the middle equation going to $-\infty$?

@Kolja Yes it would but so would the lower bound so that the middle term it still within the lower bound

Overview
Answer
Yes, all of the the proposed inequalities are true, and I present a proof below.
Summary and Opinion
The left sides of the original inequalities follow from basic geometric facts. And the generalization from the original inequalities to the form with exponents of $x$ follows from basic inequality facts and an application of the less-basic tool Jensen's inequality.
But the right hand sides of the original inequalities do not seem to follow from any standard geometric facts I could find, and I had to resort to brute force to prove them. In my view, stating them is by far the most notable part of the original post, and I wonder how they were discovered.
Geometric Facts
Inradius Facts
Inradius Equation
As mentioned in the relevant Wikipedia section, the area $A$ of a triangle equals $rs$, where $r$ is the inradius and $s$ is the semiperimeter $s=(a+b+c)/2$. We will use this later to establish the right side of the original inequality.
Inradius Inequality
In a non-degenerate triangle, every side length ($a$, $b$, $c$) is greater than the diameter of the incircle $2r$. This is intuitively obvious by looking at a diagram. And it is proven, for instance, in coffeemath's answer to Triangle side relation with incircle.
Note that, by properties of inequalities, this yields $\dfrac{1}{a},\dfrac{1}{b},\dfrac{1}{c}<\dfrac{1}{2r}$. As a result, we have $\dfrac{1}{c}<\dfrac{1}{2r}<\dfrac{1}{2r}+\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b$. Subtracting $\dfrac1c+\dfrac{1}{2r}$ from both sides yields the left side of the inradius inequality: $\boxed{-\dfrac{1}{2r}<\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b-\dfrac1c}$.
Circumradius Facts
Circumradius Equations
As mentioned in the relevant Wikipedia section, the diameter $2R$ of a triangle's circumcircle equals $\dfrac{abc}{2A}$, where $A$ is the area of the triangle. This means that $\dfrac{R}{A}=\dfrac{\frac{abc}{4A}}{A}=\dfrac{abc}{4A^2}$.
For an alternate form, we can solve for $A$, so that we have $A=\dfrac{abc}{4R}$. This means that $\dfrac{R}{A}=\dfrac{R}{\frac{abc}{4R}}=\dfrac{(2R)^2}{abc}$.
Circumradius Inequality
Note that each side of a triangle is a chord (possibly a diameter in the case of a right triangle) of its circumcircle. There are many ways to prove that we must have $a,b,c\le2R$. A few approaches are discussed in answers to Prove by contradiction that a circle chord is no longer than its diameter.
Also, note that in a non-degenerate triangle, at most one of $a,b,c$ can achieve equality (e.g. $b=2R$). One way to show this is to use the relationship to the law of sines: We have $a=2R\sin\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is the angle opposite the side of length $a$. But equality $a=2R$ requires $\alpha$ to be a right angle, and the sum of the angles in a triangle means there can be at most one right angle.
As a consequence, in a non-degenerate triangle, we have $bc,ac,ab<(2R)^2$. (For example, if $c$ is the length of the hypotenuse of a right triangle, then $c=2R$ and $b<2R$, so that $bc<(2R)^2$.) Dividing through by $abc$, we obtain $\dfrac1a,\dfrac1b,\dfrac1c<\dfrac{(2R)^2}{abc}=\dfrac{R}{A}$. As a result, we have $\dfrac1c<\dfrac{R}{A}<\dfrac{R}{A}+\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b$. Subtracting $\dfrac1c+\dfrac{R}{A}$ from both sides yields the left side of the circumradius inequality: $\boxed{-\dfrac{R}{A}<\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b-\dfrac1c}$.
Right Sides
Strategy
Note that if $c$ is not the strictly-greatest side length of the triangle, then the right sides of the inequalities would be easy given the inequalities above. For example, if $a,c\le b$ then $\dfrac1b\le \dfrac1c$ and $\dfrac1a<\dfrac{1}{2r},\dfrac{R}{A}$ from the geometry facts above. We could then add inequalities to obtain $\dfrac1b+\dfrac1a<\dfrac1c+\dfrac{1}{2r},\dfrac1c+\dfrac{R}{A}$ and hence $\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b-\dfrac1c<\dfrac{1}{2r},\dfrac{R}{A}$.
However, if $c>a,b$, then we have no such luck. In order to make these a little more straightforward to approach with brute force, note that scaling the triangle by any positive factor also scales the conjectured inequality by the reciprocal of that factor, so that it suffices to prove this for post-scaled triangles with perimeter $a+b+c=1$ (and hence semiperimeter $s=\frac12$). Note that the triangle inequality imposes a few conditions:

$a+b>c=1-(a+b)$ so that $a+b>\frac12$.
$b+c=b+(1-(a+b))=1-a>a$ so that $a<\frac12$.
Similarly, $b<\frac12$.

However, since we may assume $c>a,b$, we have $1-(a+b)>a,b$ so that we can replace the latter two inequalities with the stricter $a<\frac12(1-b)$ and $b<\frac12(1-a)$. This means that the region of the $(a,b)$-plane of interest is the triangle bounded by $a+b=\frac12$, $b=\frac12(1-a)$, and $a=\frac12(1-b)$, whose vertices are at $\left(\frac12,0\right)$, $\left(0,\frac12\right)$, and $\left(\frac13,\frac13\right)$. Note that $\left(\frac12,0\right)$ and $\left(0,\frac12\right)$ correspond to degenerate triangles.
Since we can write the radii of the relevant circles in terms of the triangle's area, and we can write the area in terms of the side lengths via Heron's formula $A^2=s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)=\frac12(\frac12-a)(\frac12-b)(a+b-\frac12)$, the right side inequalities essentially become polynomial inequalities in two variables on the triangular region of the plane described above. Moving things to one side, we'll have an expression that we need to prove is always positive on the region.
With the aid of a computer, we can handle the intricate calculations to check this. The minimum value on the triangular region with boundary must appear on the boundary or at a critical point in the interior of the triangle. It will turn out that the values at the only critical point in the interior are positive, and that the values along the edges are positive except at the vertices corresponding to degenerate triangles.
Inradius Details
We aim to show $\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b-\dfrac1c<\dfrac{1}{2r}$. Since $A=rs$, $r=A/s=2A$, and our goal is $\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b-\dfrac1c<\dfrac{1}{4\sqrt{A^2}}$. Assuming (since other cases were handled already) that $c$ is the longest side length of the triangle, we have $\dfrac1c\le\dfrac1b$ so that $\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b-\dfrac1c>0$. As such, our goal is equivalent to the inequality obtained by squaring both sides: $\left(\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b-\dfrac1c\right)^2<\dfrac{1}{16A^2}$, i.e. $\dfrac{1}{16A^2}-\left(\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b-\dfrac1c\right)^2>0$. We wish to prove the expression is positive on the triangular region.
We will use Wolfram Language (the language used by Mathematica). The computer calculations below can be found at Try it online!
expr = Together[
 1/(16*areaSq) - (1/a + 1/b - 1/(1 - (a + b)))^2 /. 
  areaSq -> 1/2 (1/2 - a) (1/2 - b) (a + b - 1/2)]

gives the expression in terms of just $a$ and $b$ as a single fraction.
Denominator[expr] returns a^2 (-1 + 2 a) b^2 (-1 + a + b)^2 (-1 + 2 b) (-1 + 2 a + 2 b). The square factors are positive. $(-1 + 2 a)$ and $(-1 + 2 b)$ are both negative so their signs cancel. $(-1 + 2 a + 2 b)$ is positive. Therefore, the denominator is positive, and our objective function is the numerator: obj = Numerator[expr], a polynomial with $31$ terms.
Solve[a + b >= 1/2 && 1 - (a + b) >= b && 1 - (a + b) >= a && Grad[obj, {a, b}] == 0, {a, b}]
returns {{a -> 0, b -> 1/2}, {a -> 2/7, b -> 2/7}, {a -> 1/2, b -> 0}}, so that there is one critical point of the objective function in the interior of the region: $\left(\frac27,\frac27\right)$. obj /. {a -> 2/7, b -> 2/7} returns 432/823543$>0$.
Now we can check the boundary segments:
Factor[(obj /. b -> 1/2 - a)] produces (a^2*(-1 + 2*a)^2)/16, which is positive in the interior of the segment from $(a,b)=\left(\frac12,0\right)$ to $(a,b)=\left(0,\frac12\right)$.
Factor[(obj /. b -> 1/2 (1 - a))] produces ((-1 + a)^4*a^3)/8, which is positive on the interval $\left[\frac13,\frac12\right)$.
Factor[(obj /. a -> 1/2 (1 - b))] produces ((-1 + b)^4*b^3)/8 which is positive on the relevant segment for exactly the same reason as the previous segment.
Since the objective function is positive on the boundary segments (except the two vertices corresponding to degenerate triangles with $a=0$ or $b=0$) and at the critical point on the interior of the triangular region, it must be positive on the whole relevant region, as desired. In other words, even if $c>a,b$, we have $\boxed{\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b-\dfrac1c<\dfrac{1}{2r}}$.
Circumradius Details
We aim to show $\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b-\dfrac1c<\dfrac{R}{A}=\dfrac{abc}{4A^2}$, i.e. $\dfrac{abc}{4A^2}-\left(\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b-\dfrac1c\right)>0$. We wish to prove the expression is positive on the triangular region.
We will use Wolfram Language (the language used by Mathematica). The computer calculations below can be found at Try it online!
expr = Together[(a*b*(1 - (a + b)))/(4*areaSquared) - (1/a + 1/b - 1/(1 - (a + b))) /. 
   areaSquared -> 1/2 (1/2 - a) (1/2 - b) (a + b - 1/2)];

gives the expression in terms of just $a$ and $b$ as a single fraction.
Denominator[expr] returns a (-1 + 2 a) b (-1 + a + b) (-1 + 2 b) (-1 + 2 a + 2 b), which is negative as $a,b,-1+2a+2b>0$ and $-1+2a,-1+2b,-1+a+b<0$. This means our objective function is the negative of the numerator: obj = -Numerator[expr], a polynomial with $21$ terms.
crit = Solve[a + b >= 1/2 && 1 - (a + b) > b && 1 - (a + b) > a && Grad[obj, {a, b}] == 0, {a, b}]
returns {{a -> [root of quartic], b -> [root of quartic system]}}, so that there is one critical point of the objective function in the interior of the region.
By checking with Reduce[b == a /. crit], we confirm that the values are merely the same root of the quartic $24x^4+92x^3-82x^2+19x-1$, namely the value $a=b\approx0.2994236$.
The numerical approximation of the value of the objective function at that critical point is N[obj /. crit], which returns 0.00038363040590000397, which is positive beyond the margin of computational error.
Now we can check the boundary segments:
Factor[(obj /. b -> 1/2 - a)] produces (a^2 (-1 + 2 a)^2)/4, which is positive in the interior of the segment from $(a,b)=\left(\frac12,0\right)$ to $(a,b)=\left(0,\frac12\right)$.
Factor[(obj /. b -> 1/2 (1 - a))] produces ((-1 + a)^2*a^4)/4, which is positive on the interval $\left[\frac13,\frac12\right)$.
Factor[(obj /. a -> 1/2 (1 - b))] produces ((-1 + b)^2*b^4)/4 which is positive on the relevant segment for exactly the same reason as the previous segment.
Since the objective function is positive on the boundary segments (except the two vertices corresponding to degenerate triangles with $a=0$ or $b=0$) and at the critical point on the interior of the triangular region, it must be positive on the whole relevant region, as desired. In other words, even if $c>a,b$, we have $\boxed{\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b-\dfrac1c<\dfrac{R}{A}}$.
Exponents
Left Sides
By our geometric facts, we have $\dfrac{1}{c}<\dfrac{1}{2r},\dfrac{R}{A}$.
For $x>0$ (not even just $x\ge1$!), the function $f(t)=t^{x}$ is increasing for positive $t$, so we have $\left(\dfrac{1}{c}\right)^{x}<\left(\dfrac{1}{2r}\right)^{x},\left(\dfrac{R}{A}\right)^{x}$.
Adding the positive $\left(\dfrac{1}{a}\right)^{x}+\left(\dfrac{1}{b}\right)^{x}$ to the right side yields $\left(\dfrac{1}{c}\right)^{x}<\left(\dfrac{1}{a}\right)^{x}+\left(\dfrac{1}{b}\right)^{x}+\left(\dfrac{1}{2r}\right)^{x},\left(\dfrac{1}{a}\right)^{x}+\left(\dfrac{1}{b}\right)^{x}+\left(\dfrac{R}{A}\right)^{x}$.
Finally, subtracting $\left(\dfrac{1}{c}\right)^{x}+\left(\dfrac{1}{2r}\right)^{x}$ or $\left(\dfrac{1}{c}\right)^{x}+\left(\dfrac{R}{A}\right)^{x}$ from both sides yields the desired $\boxed{-\dfrac{1}{2^{x}r^{x}},-\left(\dfrac{R}{A}\right)^{x}<\dfrac{1}{a^{x}}+\dfrac{1}{b^{x}}-\dfrac{1}{c^{x}}}$.
Right Sides
For the right-hand sides, we need to do a little casework.
Case 1: $c\le b$. Then as discussed before, we have $\dfrac{1}{b}\le\dfrac{1}{c}$ and $\dfrac{1}{a}<\dfrac{1}{2r},\dfrac{R}{A}$. As long as $x>0$, we can raise both of these inequalities to the exponent $x$ and add them together to obtain $\left(\dfrac{1}{a}\right)^{x}+\left(\dfrac{1}{b}\right)^{x}<\left(\dfrac{1}{c}\right)^{x}+\left(\dfrac{1}{2r}\right)^{x},\left(\dfrac{1}{c}\right)^{x}+\left(\dfrac{R}{A}\right)^{x}$. Subtracting $\left(\dfrac{1}{c}\right)^{x}$ from both sides yields the desired result.
Case 2: $c\le a$. This is completely analogous to Case 1.
Case 3: The real case of concern is $c>a,b$ so that $\dfrac{1}{c}<\dfrac{1}{a},\dfrac{1}{b}$. Without loss of generality, assume $\dfrac{1}{a}\ge\dfrac{1}{b}$. Note that geometric facts give us $\dfrac{1}{b}\le\dfrac{1}{a}<\dfrac{1}{2r},\dfrac{R}{A}$. It is this case where we need $x\ge1$. For intuition, our situation is similar to $2+3\le1+4\Rightarrow2^{2}+3^{2}<1^{2}+4^{2}$: the sum of the powers of the outer terms is greater. Our aim is to use Jensen's inequality. (This approach is adapted from the closely-related proof found on the Art of Problem Solving Forums at naman12's reply in the thread "A hard inequality in a TST contest".)
Earlier, we proved the case of $x=1$, that $\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}<\dfrac{1}{c}+\dfrac{1}{2r},\dfrac{1}{c}+\dfrac{R}{A}$ . Set $m$ to be $\left(\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}\right)/2$ so that $2m<\dfrac{1}{c}+\dfrac{1}{2r},\dfrac{1}{c}+\dfrac{R}{A}$. For convenience, define $\circledR$ to be $\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}-\dfrac{1}{c}$, so that $\circledR<\dfrac{1}{2r},\dfrac{R}{A}$ and $m=\left(\circledR+\dfrac{1}{c}\right)/2$.
Note that $\dfrac{1}{a}<\dfrac{1}{a}+\left(\dfrac{1}{b}-\dfrac{1}{c}\right)=\circledR$ and similarly $\dfrac{1}{b}\le\dfrac{1}{a}<\circledR$. Since $\dfrac{1}{a}\ge\dfrac{1}{b}$, we have $m\le\dfrac{1}{a}<\circledR$, so that there is some $t$ satisfying $0\le t<1$ where $\dfrac{1}{a}=t\circledR+\left(1-t\right)m$. Then $\dfrac{1}{b}=2m-\dfrac{1}{a}=2m-2tm+2tm-\dfrac{1}{a}$ $=2m-2tm+t\left(\circledR+\dfrac{1}{c}\right)-\left(t\circledR+\left(1-t\right)m\right)=\left(1-t\right)m+t\left(\dfrac{1}{c}\right)$.
We have that $f(t)=t^{x}$ is convex since $f''(t)=x\left(x-1\right)t^{x-2}>0$ for $t>0$. By Jensen's inequality, we have $\left(\dfrac{1}{a}\right)^{x}=\left(t\circledR+\left(1-t\right)m\right)^{x}\le t\circledR^{x}+\left(1-t\right)m^{x}$. Similarly, $\left(\dfrac{1}{b}\right)^{x}=\left(\left(1-t\right)m+t\left(\dfrac{1}{c}\right)\right)^{x}\le t\left(\dfrac{1}{c}\right)^{x}+\left(1-t\right)m^{x}$.
Adding these together yields $\left(\dfrac{1}{a}\right)^{x}+\left(\dfrac{1}{b}\right)^{x}\le t\left(\circledR^{x}+\left(\dfrac{1}{c}\right)^{x}\right)+2\left(1-t\right)m^{x}$.
By another application of Jensen's, we also have $2m^{x}=2\left(\dfrac{\circledR}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2c}\right)^{x}\le\circledR^{x}+\left(\dfrac{1}{c}\right)^{x}$.
Combining the results, we have $\left(\dfrac{1}{a}\right)^{x}+\left(\dfrac{1}{b}\right)^{x}\le\circledR^{x}+\left(\dfrac{1}{c}\right)^{x}$. Since $\circledR<\dfrac{1}{2r},\dfrac{R}{A}$, this yields the desired $\boxed{\left(\dfrac{1}{a}\right)^{x}+\left(\dfrac{1}{b}\right)^{x}-\left(\dfrac{1}{c}\right)^{x}\le\dfrac{1}{2^xr^x},\left(\dfrac{R}{A}\right)^{x}}$.

That is a lot of work !!!

@NilotpalSinha I'm still holding out hope that someone will swoop in with an obscure geometry fact that takes care of the hard part without brute force.

Some thoughts.
Let $x := \frac{c + a - b}{2}, y := \frac{a + b - c}{2}, z := \frac{b + c - a}{2}$. Then $x, y, z > 0$ and
$a = x + y, b = y + z, c = z + x$.
We have
$$r = \sqrt{\frac{xyz}{x + y + z}},\quad \frac{R}{A} = \frac{(x + y)(y + z)(z + x)}{4(x + y + z)xyz}.$$
The desired inequalities are written as: for $x, y, z > 0$,
$$- \frac{\sqrt{x + y + z}}{2\sqrt{xyz}}
< \frac{1}{x + y} + \frac{1}{y + z} - \frac{1}{z + x} < \frac{\sqrt{x + y + z}}{2\sqrt{xyz}}, \tag{1}$$
and
$$- \frac{(x + y)(y + z)(z + x)}{4(x + y + z)xyz}
< \frac{1}{x + y} + \frac{1}{y + z} - \frac{1}{z + x} < \frac{(x + y)(y + z)(z + x)}{4(x + y + z)xyz}. \tag{2}$$
(1) and (2) are true. But I want to see a nice proof (e.g. without squaring both sides with full expanding).

Are you saying $(1)$ and $(2)$ based on Mark's proof or because there is some tedious algebraic proof which squares and expands both sides and you are looking for a nicer proof?

@NilotpalSinha Left side of (1) and (2) is easy. Right side of (2) is not difficult. Only Right side of (1) requires nice proof, squaring both sides is not nice, I think. We may let $y = 1$ and $p = x + z, q = xz$, for example.

I wonder if we can prove that the upper and the lower bound must have the same absolute value. In that case proving either left or right will be sufficient. I have posted my heuristic intuition behind this inequality but is calculus driven rather than geometrical.

@NilotpalSinha I have no idea. I guess no better than directly proof of right inequality.

Here is a heuristic argument to justify the intution behind the inequalities. Consider an isosceles triangle with sides $a = b = 2R - \epsilon_1,c = \epsilon_2$ where $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ are small quantities. The area of this triangle will be approximately
$$
A = \frac{(2R - \epsilon_1)\epsilon_2}{2} \approx \epsilon_2 R 
$$
Hence
$$
\frac{1}{a^x} + \frac{1}{b^x} - \frac{1}{c^x} = \frac{2}{(2R - \epsilon_1)^x} - \frac{1}{\epsilon_2^x} \approx - \frac{1}{\epsilon_2^x} \approx -\frac{R^x}{A^x} \tag 1
$$
Similarly consider another triangle with sides $a = c = 2R - \epsilon_1, b = \epsilon_2$. For this triangle
$$
\frac{1}{a^x} + \frac{1}{b^x} - \frac{1}{c^x} = \frac{1}{\epsilon_2^x} \approx \frac{R^x}{A^x} \tag 2
$$
In the limiting case when $\epsilon_1 \to 0$ we have $\epsilon_2 \to 0$ the approximation in $(1)$ and $(2)$ approach equality. Hence the lowerbound is at least $-\frac{R^x}{A^x}$ and the upper bound is at least $\frac{R^x}{A^x}$.
